# How can i organise my REST endpoints better .Using apache cxf REST framework

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I am trying to find out how to organise my REST APIs. I have a lot of end points 
in following fashion :

```
public interface MyService {    
@GET
@Path("/A")
@Produces("application/json")
Response status();

@GET
@Path("/A/x")
@Produces("application/json")
Response getX();

@GET
@Path("/B")
@Produces("application/json")
Response getB() throws Exception;

@GET
@Path("/B/y")
@Produces("application/json")
Response getY() throws Exception;   
...
...
}
```

I have used Spring to config like

```
<jaxrs:server id="platform" address="/platform">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
           <ref bean="myService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="com.x.Y"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Now as I have huge number of endpoints and i want to organise my endpoints in the following way :

```
    @Path("/A")
    public interface NotificationEventService extends MyService{    

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    Response status();

    @GET
    @Path("/x")
    @Produces("application/json")
    Response getX();

  }


@Path("/B")
public interface NotificationEventService extends MyService{    

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    Response getB() throws Exception;

    @GET
    @Path("/y")
    @Produces("application/json")
    Response getY() throws Exception;
  }
```

The problem is how do i instantiate my beans and do the request mapping ?

The code is bit of a legacy and i am not that thorough with apache CXf

Comment: Can you clarify *how do i instantiate my beans and do the request mapping*?

Comment: I have added my MyService as a service bean and it has all the request mappings. Now how do i bring my new interface implementation into play. Where do i add them , so that when i get a request some api , it does to the correct implementation.